# Failing to reconnect to Internet on wakeup: OSX 10.10.5 (14F27) MacBook Pro Retina (late 2013)

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking

I've been having this issue for a while, but not the whole life of the machine: upon waking from sleep (closed laptop or sleep due to inactivity) the wireless adapter will connect to the access point, but I will have no connectivity to the Internet at large. That is, I have "full bars" in the top bar indicator, and can reach the wireless AP config page (e.g. 192.168.0.1 or whatever it's running on), but won't be able to reach www.google.com. If I bounce the wireless on my laptop, or switch to another network running on the same modem/AP device, I'm reconnected. I'm (sadly) on Time Warner w/Arris DGI1670 (though I also believe this behavior is exhibited on other networks).

```
DHCP Configuration
IP address: 192.168.0.4
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.0.1
Client ID: 
IPv6: Automatic
IPv6 IP address: none
IPv6 Router: none
Wi-Fi ID: b8:[redacted]:1e

$ networksetup -getwebproxy Wi-Fi
Enabled: No
Server: 
Port: 0
Authenticated Proxy Enabled: 0
```

Any guidance on troubleshooting this would be appreciated. I know my way around bash, but don't have the firmest grasp of network architecture. Glad to learn, of course!

Comment: This wreaks of some sort of TTL setting on your connection but I can't find where this would be configured in `networksetup`. Please provide more network info like config, proxy, auth (if any), etc.

Comment: I added some details above. Hope that helps, otherwise, let me know